# AWS Lambda > what happens when reach concurrent limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Lambda has a 100 function limit.

What happens when you submit a 101 function when 100 are already running?

Will it:

- fail with an error
- queue up

Comment: It used to be `100`. They increased it to `1000`. You can request AWS to increase it. Rest if explained in @MaiKaY's answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you are talking about `Concurrent executions` there isn't a limit of 100. The limit [depends on the region](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_lambda) but by default it's 1000 `Concurrent executions`.

To answer your question: As soon as the `Concurrent executions` limit is reached the next execution gets throttled. Each throttled invocation increases the Amazon CloudWatch `Throttles` metric for the function.

If your AWS Lambda is invoked **asynchronous** AWS Lambda automatically retries the throttled event for up to six hours, with delays between retries. If you didn't setup a [Dead Letter Queue (DLQ)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dlq.html) for your AWS Lambda your event is lost as soon as all retries fails.

For more information please check the [AWS Lambda - Throttling Behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html#throttling-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

> If the function doesn't have enough concurrency available to process all events, additional requests are throttled. For throttling errors (429) and system errors (500-series), Lambda returns the event to the queue and attempts to run the function again for up to 6 hours. The retry interval increases exponentially from 1 second after the first attempt to a maximum of 5 minutes. However, it might be longer if the queue is backed up. Lambda also reduces the rate at which it reads events from the queue.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html).